# PHP character escape sequence does not work

Tags: php, eclipse, web, escaping, wampserver

I am an extreme web programming beginner who is just starting to learn PHP with some knowledge of HTML and JavaScript.

I use WAMP Server as my web server and Eclipse PDT as my IDE.
I created a .php file in Eclipse.
I just want to run a simple code that I pulled from a text book:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World\napple";
?>
```

However, the line break does not work and it just makes a space.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are displaying the code with a browser, you should either change the \n to be <br> or wrap the string in an nl2br call - like echo nl2br("Hello World\napple");

Comment: It works, but how come the example is written without the nl2br call in the book? Also, why did my IDE read <br> as an error?

Comment: Just want to say that if you're going to use line breaks, you'd best use PHP_EOL -  it is cross-platform.

Comment: If you run it on the command line with \n, it will display as expected.  To run on the command line, use:

php hello.php.

Comment: @Qub1 how do I run PHP_EOL on Eclipse?

Comment: echo 'Hello World'.PHP_EOL.'apple';